# Commerce Kickstart won't install

Tags: commerce

Running latest versions of Drupal, modules and Commerce Kickstart
with Ubuntu, 4 GB RAM
Low Free Hard Drive Space, Swap file 2installs50 MB

I have read the posted how to installs but it still won't install.  I have only 1 GB of free space but I'm not sure that is the problem.   I suspect Kickstart unpacks itself and installs all at once, but I do not know.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Commerce Kickstart is a profile of Drupal and so you just have to select commerce kickstart radio button during your installation of Drupal. After selecting this, Drupal will start installing default products and all.
Download Commerce Kickstart and install it same as you install Drupal.

Answer (score 0):

Commerce Kickstart has drupal core installed and so you dont need to install drupal core.
You should directly install commerce kickstart.

The commerce Kickstart has the drupal core.